# Bar graphs with different range bars

Tags: data-visualization, dataset, barplot, matplotlib

I have the following bar graph -

[image]

1. Is it ok to have bars of different ranges or is it misleading? For example, the range of the first bar is 0-10M. The range of the last bar is 500M - $1B. The person who made this told me they did it this way because our data is skewed but is this ok to do or will it be misleading the end user?
2. If it is misleading, is there a better way to plot this?

Comment: Personally, I would find it a bit misleading. Maybe you can use a logarithmic scale instead?

Comment: This is a great way to fool naive viewers, because with most datasets you can make the pattern of bars look like anything you want merely by choosing suitable breakpoints.  Thus, for this visualization to be legitimate and useful, you need some principle for choosing the breakpoints.  "Data is skewed" is an *indicator* that something might need to be done, but by itself it is no principle.  What, then, was the method for determining the breakpoints; how is that communicated to the viewer; and what is the purpose of this plot?